# AWS Device farming services issue for react-native app testing. Need to test the app on multiple android and IOS devices.

Tags: aws-device-farm, detox

Is there any service which supports device farming to test the test suite on different devices. I am facing this problem as AWS (Amazon web services) does not support device forming for react-native apps.

Need help! Please inform or suggest if some body is using these kind of device farming third party services for testing the detox test cases.

Answer (score 0):

I work for the AWS Device Farm team.

Here is one way to test react native apps on AWS Device Farm using Espresso. 
https://www.slideshare.net/AmazonWebServices/device-testing-with-aws-device-farm-89135178

The central idea here is to use the Espresso recorder functionality to work for react native apps.

Hope that helps.

Comment: My current understanding is that Espresso tests are for android only? is there any way to record or write tests that can execute on both ios and android (given the react-native app is identical on both platforms)

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there's no cloud service with Detox support yet, but you can write your tests in Appium to test both platforms - you just need to fire separate test run for each platform, but the Appium tests can stay same.